# jQuery $(this) selector not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a jQuery carousel plugin that I'm using more dynamic by adding some additions features to it.

```
$("ul#carousel").roundabout();

$("ul#carousel li").click(function() { 
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var id_num = id.substr(-1);

    for( var i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        if(i != id_num)
        {                   
              $("li#list_"+ i +" .table_box").attr("class", "table_box");
        }
    }

    $(this +" .table_box").attr("class", "sub_table_box");
});
```

The php

```
<ul id="carousel">
<?php
     for($i=0;$i<4;$i++)
     {
          echo "<li id='list_".$i."'>
                   <div class='table_box'>

                   </div>
                </li>";
     }
 ?>
 </ul>
```

In Chrome's javascript console, upon click of the list item I get an error reading:

```
 Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object HTMLLIElement]
```

on my jquery-1.7.min.js file.

I'm thinking that it might have something to do with the plugin script conflicting with one of the other js file. But, jquery noconflict didn't solve anything unless I tried it wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's simply not how jQuery and DOM APIs work. `this` is an HTML element, so you can't just string-concatenate it to query its children. Change

```
$(this +" .table_box")
```

to

```
$(this).find(".table_box")
```

> What about the elements inside of the for loop? I tried using $(this).find("li#list_"+ i +" .table_box").attr("class", "table_box"); but that didn't work.

That's because `this` is already an `<li>`. You can replace the entire loop with this:

```
$(this).siblings().find('.sub_table_box').removeClass('sub_table_box').addClass('table_box');
```

To summarize (and add a few other style improvements):

```
$("ul#carousel").on('click', 'li', function() {
    $(this)
        .addClass('sub_table_box');
        .siblings()
        .find('.sub_table_box')
        .removeClass('sub_table_box')
        .addClass('table_box');
});
```

Comment: What about the elements inside of the for loop? I tried using  $(this).find("li#list_"+ i +" .table_box").attr("class", "table_box"); but that didn't work.

Comment: @Lance, what is that supposed to do? It says "find elements in this that **have the class "table_box"** within an element that has a specific id and **set their class to "table_box"** which is a little pointless.

Comment: This is common sense jQuery. 6 upvotes in under 10 minutes? RTFM people lol.

Comment: @AlienWebguy not disagreeing there.

Comment: Your "solution" doesn't work. Upon further scrutiny under firebug, it appears that no classes are being changed.

Comment: This worked though: $(this).siblings().find(".sub_table_box").removeClass("sub_table_box").addClass("table_box");

Comment: @Lance you're right. My mistake. Glad to see you were able to do some of your own debugging `:)`

Comment: Hahahaha. Very funny. I don't use jquery much since it kinda of slows things down.

Comment: "slows things down"? what, like development?